# Which Android Operating Systems are supported by OpenCV?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Which Android Operating Systems are supported by [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/)?

It seems that the bare minimum in the examples is 3.0, but does anyone know if you can support older devices?  Also vice versa, can it support ICS?  How about 4.1 or 4.2?  I can't seem to find specifics anywhere and I don't want to buy a test device that it's not going to work on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It supports all releases starting from Android 2.2 (API level 8).

The minimum you see in examples is a compile-time only. The code checks current OS version at run time and chooses better implementation if the API level is high enough, otherwise it fallbacks to legacy implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I see a little talk about 4.0 support, but no mentions of anything newer.  I'd like to be able to test on one of those new Nexus 4's

Answer (score 1):

There are no reasons to believe it will not work with nexus4 4.2. Corrections were made for issues on some 4.2 devices as you can read here in the [release notes](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/Android_Release_Notes). So you can see people have been testing it with 4.2.